# add parameters into callback function

Tags: javascript

Would like to pass parameters into a callback function and unsure of how to do so in this format

```
player.GetPlayer((name,surname) -> {
    var thisPlayerId = player.id;
});
```

in this case perhaps a username and password into a GetPlayer function

```
 module.exports = class Player{

constructor(){
    this.username = ""
    this.id = 0;

}

GetPlayer(Callback,name,surname)
{   
    console.log(name)
    console.log(surname)
    var player = this;
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name = UserName ', function (err, result,fields) {

            if (err) console.log(err)

            // send records as a response
            //console.log(result.recordset[0].PlayerID);
            player.username = result.recordset[0].UserName;
            player.id = result.recordset[0].PlayerID;
            sql.close();
    Callback();
        });
    });
}
```

}

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: You have to modifie the "GetPlayer" function, or just add a wrapper if you have already access to the parameter you want to pass.( (p1, p2) => { finalCB(p1, p2, user, data, ...) })

Comment: @Marc how would i edit my getplayer function ? i have callback at the end of it so a bit difficult ?

Comment: @J.Alex Where does this function come from ? Is it written by yourself or from a framework? Can you add more code ? Do you have allready access to "username" & "password" parameters ? where come they from?

Comment: @Marc this is my own , the username and password will come from input boxes from the user which will then compare against an sql database in the GetPlayer function just wondering how to pass those parameters through

Comment: @J.Alex Please add more code, anything else is just guessing and a waste of time

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Is it just refactoring the second function into the first one? Or are you trying to use the second form but pass parameters to Callback()? Where do you have defined the function you pass as Callback or what signature does it have?

Comment: Sorry all , have updated code to show more detail hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your GetPlayer function

```js
GetPlayer(Callback,name,surname){
...
}
```

Add your needed paramters to your "Callback"

```js
// query to the database and get the records
 request.query('SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name = UserName ', function (err, result,fields) {

    // callback
    // now your are able to access username&password in your callback function
    Callback(username, password, ...);
    
});
```

Comment: As useful as this is how would i add the parameters i wish to pass to: var name = "BOB"
    var surname = "BOB2"
    player.GetPlayer((name,surname) => {
        var thisPlayerId = player.id;});

Comment: You must call the "GetPlayer" with this paramters! They got not passed in your callback. You are calling the function with them! "player.GetPlayer((username, password, ...) => { console.log(...)}, "John", "Doe")


EDIT: Based on your post & questions, is it possible that you want to create a login function?

Comment: @mark GetPlayer(Callback,name,surname)var name = "BOB"
    var surname = "BOB2"
    {   }Callback(name,surname);player.GetPlayer((name,surname) => {

Comment: all 3 have same named parameters ?

Comment: and yes i am creating a login function

Comment: @J.AlexI Im confused... AND, for the love of your users, please, PLEASE! Hash the users password and DON'T store it in plain text!

Comment: do you have anywhere else we can talk ? discord or just somewhere else cant seem to PM you

Answer (score 0):

In Java you have to use `->` instead of `=>` .

EDIT.

So if you are using javascript, you only need to define that a callback is received on your function

```
function doHomework(subject, callback) {
  alert(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`);
  callback();
}

doHomework('math', function() {
  alert('Finished my homework');
});
```

Comment: He is using javascript. We don't have function in java, no cb. And lambda in java is similar to arrow function in js.

Comment: The question was tagged as Java before.

Comment: I understand your confusion.

Comment: My bad ill tag as javascript